# Why is $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\ln(21-4(\cos x+\cos y+\cos(x+y)))}{2\ln(9/2)}\frac{dx}{2\pi} \frac{dy}{2\pi}$ almost $1$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms, multiple-integral, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the function
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{\ln(21-4(\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)))}{2\ln(9/2)} $$

Its average value is awfully close to unity:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x,y) \frac{\mathrm dx}{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm d y}{2\pi} = 1.00095 $$
(This result is [rounded](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%201%2F%288*pi**2%29*ln%2821-4*%28cos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29%2Bcos%28x%2By%29%29%29%2Fln%289%2F2%29%20for%20x%20%3D%200..2pi%20and%20y%20%3D%200..%202pi).)

Is this just a fluke, or is there some deeper reason to it?

Comment: That function has a few seemingly-arbitrary constants. It's not surprising to me that you can could tweak those parameters to make this integral close to $1$.

Comment: @JairTaylor That's true. I obtained the above function from a particular physics set-up, so it was not tweaked in any way. But I agree that when written in isolation as above, it seems as if someone chose it to work.

Comment: We have a periodic function evaluated over an entire period.  If we plug in the average value over that period we get $\frac {\ln 21}{2\ln \frac 92} = 1.012$

Comment: I didn't think you intentionally tweaked the constants to be close to one, but for it to be mathematically significant I would want the function to be more "natural" in some sense.  Maybe if you explained some of the physics it would help. [You could also try on physics.se.]